# rails: text not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class MyTestController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render_text "hello world"
    end
end
```

This is what I am getting when I go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/My_Test/ :

> NoMethodError in My testController#index
>
> undefined method `render_text' for #
>   RAILS_ROOT: C:/rails/rails_apps/cookbook
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/my_test_controller.rb:5:in `index'
>   Request
>
> Parameters:
>   None
>
> Show session dump
>
> Response Headers:
>
> {"cookie"=>[], "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}

please keep in mind i am following this tutorial:

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/archive/rails.html?page=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial is very old and out of date. The `render_text` method no longer exists. Try the following instead:

```
def index
  render :text => "hello world"
end
```

Comment: thank you phil!! can you reecomend some up to date tutorials?

Comment: @every_answer You might like to take a look at the Getting Started with Rails guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html